Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)}{n }$ absolute convergent?
I'm investigating the convergence characteristics of the series.
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)}{n },
$$
and I'm trying to determine whether this series is absolutely convergent. In one hand if look at the series formed by taking the absolute value of each term:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left| \frac{\sin(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)}{n } \right|.
$$
I've started by examining the behavior of the series' terms. The argument of the sine function, $\sqrt{n^2+1}-n$, can be tricky to handle due to the square root and subtraction. However, a Taylor expansion or a binomial approximation suggests that $\sqrt{n^2+1}-n$ behaves like $\frac{1}{2n}$ for large $n$. This is because:
$$
\sqrt{n^2+1} \approx n + \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{8n^3} + \ldots,
$$
which means the term inside the sine approximately becomes $\frac{1}{2n}$ for very large $n$. Thus, the sine function's argument tends toward zero as $n$ increases.
But by using dirichlet theorem, I see that its conditional convergence, and when i check for absolute, if I multiply and divided by $${\sqrt{n^2+1}-n} $$. So I will have $$\frac{sin(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n} \frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{n}$$,  then when x->0 lim to inf so $$\frac{sin(x)}{x} = 1 $$, I now have $$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{n} $$ which is bigger then $$\frac{1}{n}$$ which is diverge so from the direct comparing test its also diverge and the original is diverge. (I think i did something wrong here, but I am not sure)
Could someone provide insights or further steps to confirm whether the series is absolutely convergent or conditional convergence?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

What have you tried?

By using dirichlet theorem, I show that its conditional convergence, but for absolute, I multiply and divided by (sqrt(n^2+1)-n). So I will have sin(x)/x, then when x->0 lim to inf, I now have 1/n which is diverge. (I think I wrong)

Another possible approach:
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{\sin\left(\sqrt{n^{2} + 1} - n\right)}{n}\right| & \leq \frac{\sqrt{n^{2} + 1} - n}{n} = \frac{1}{n\left(\sqrt{n^{2} + 1} + n\right)} \leq \frac{1}{2n^{2}} \leq \frac{1}{n^{2}}
\end{align*}

A series $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent if $\sum |a_n|$ converges. To analyze the given series, we first simplify the argument of the sine function and then apply the comparison test to the absolute value of the series' terms.
Simplification of the Sine Argument
For large $n$, we can approximate $\sqrt{n^2+1}-n$ using a binomial expansion or by rationalizing the expression:
$$
\sqrt{n^2+1}-n = \frac{(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n} \approx \frac{1}{2n}.
$$
This approximation allows us to consider $\sin\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\right)$ as $\sin\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)$ for large $n$.
Analysis of Absolute Convergence
Given the approximation, we analyze the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left| \frac{\sin \left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{n} \right|.
$$
For small angles, $\sin(x) \approx x$, which gives us
$$
\left| \frac{\sin \left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{n} \right| \approx \frac{1}{2n^2}.
$$
This series is a p-series with $p = 2$, which is known to converge. Therefore, the original series is absolutely convergent, as it is comparable to a convergent p-series.
Conclusion
The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\right)}{n}$ is absolutely convergent. This conclusion is based on the approximation of the sine function for small angles and the comparison to a convergent p-series.

It is against the rules of MSE to answer questions without context. Please read: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

Thanks. Can you explain to me why what I tried is wrong: By using dirichlet theorem, I show that its conditional convergence, but for absolute, I multiply and divided by (sqrt(n^2+1)-n). So I will have sin(x)/x, then when x->0 lim to inf, I now have 1/n which is diverge. I also tried to say that (sqrt(n^2+1)-n)/n is bigger than 1/n, so both diverge and because of that also the original diverge.

@geetha290krm Thank you for the comment. All right, easy - I will edit the question in a second.
